# CodeIgniter - Database Transaction

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, innodb, database-deadlocks

Is `$this->db->trans_start();` is only applicable for `$this->db->query();` ?

I just want to know since all CI examples in the user guide uses `$this->db->query();`

does it applicable for this one? Example:

```
  $this->db->select('an_baby.parent_number');
  $this->db->from('an_parent');
  $this->db->join('an_baby', 'an_baby.parent_number = an_parent.id', 'inner');
  $this->db->where('date_born <=', date('Y-m-d'));
  $this->db->where('type', 'NewBorn');
```

Any response is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every CI database function between $this->db->trans_start() and $this->db->trans_complete() is good.

Answer (score 2):

Yes transactions will work fine with the active record style methods.